# Bulk load data conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to load data from csv into an SQL table.

My DDL:

```
  CREATE TABLE pcm.dbo.partitiondocumentcount 
    ( 
       partitionkey  NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
       documentcount INT NOT NULL, 
       datetime      DATETIME2(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
       CONSTRAINT pk_partitiondocumentcount PRIMARY KEY (partitionkey ASC) 
    ) 

  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX partitionkey_index 
    ON pcm.dbo.partitiondocumentcount (partitionkey AS
```

My file (I also tried without the quote marks, didn't work as well) :

```
"partition-1",1
"partition-2",1
```

My query:

```
BULK INSERT partitionDocumentCount
FROM 'C:\files\pcmInitialConfiguration\partitionCount.csv'
WITH(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
SELECT * FROM partitionDocumentCount
```

There error I get from DBVisualizer:

```
 15:36:26  [BULK - 0 row(s), 0.008 secs]  [Error Code: 4864, SQL State: S0001]  Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 2 (documentcount).
 15:36:26  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.004 secs]  Empty result set fetched
... 2 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.012/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 1 warnings, 1 errors]
```

Comment: Maybe you have a lank line or a headline in your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply add a column.
I guess since my table had three columns it expected three in the file.

My file (I also tried without the quote marks, didn't work as well) :
Here's the working one

```
partition-1,1,
partition-2,1,
```

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem in your approach, but I'm not sure it would generate that error.  The table has three columns but your data only has two.  Even with a `default` constraint, `bulk insert` still looks for the third column.  It might get that error because it is looking for a comma but encounters an end-of-line.

The solution to that is to use a view:

```
create view pcm.dbo.partitiondocumentcount_2 as
    select partitionkey, documentcount
    from pcm.dbo.partitiondocumentcount;
```

Then:

```
BULK INSERT partitionDocumentCount_2
FROM 'C:\files\pcmInitialConfiguration\partitionCount.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
     );
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the view solution, very creative. I preffered to just add a comma indicating a new empty column, SQL seems to know that and use the default value

Comment: @AlexChaplianka . . . That happens to work in this case, but that is often not a feasible solution (CSV files can be quite big).  In addition, I don't think you can input an `identity` that way.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188365.aspx for BULK INSERT options.

> CODEPAGE = { 'ACP' | 'OEM' | 'RAW' | 'code_page' } Specifies the code
>   page of the data in the data file. CODEPAGE is relevant only if the
>   data contains char, varchar, or text columns with character values
>   greater than 127 or less than 32.